# Quarkus OpenApi adding x-tokenName extension to SecurityScheme in application.properties

Tags: java, openapi, quarkus

I want to add the x-tokenName extension to the openApi security scheme component in quarkus using the application.properties file. I'am using microsoft as provider for openIdConnect, and therefore i got a response containing an access_token and a id_token.

My configuration so far, look somehow like this:

```
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme=oidc
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-name=OpenId
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oidc-open-id-connect-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

The corresponding openapi.yaml looks for the security scheme part like this:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    OpenId:
      type: openIdConnect
      description: Authentication
      openIdConnectUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

I did not find any possibility, to add x-tokenName with properties like this (or similiar):

```
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-extension=tokenName:id_token
```

to achieve a corresponding openapi.yaml like this:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    OpenId:
      type: openIdConnect
      description: Authentication
      openIdConnectUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
      x-tokenName: id_token
```

As far as i know, these extension are part of openApi and should work. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding x-* to the security model is not possible with config (at the moment). But I think that would be a valid feature to request, so please do so in the issues.

What you can do for now is to create your own Filter (that is all that it is under the covers).

See https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-open-api-1.0/microprofile-openapi-spec.html#_oasfilter

And the current filter in Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/smallrye-openapi/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/smallrye/openapi/deployment/filter/SecurityConfigFilter.java